# FFmpeg: how can I upscale a video using scale_qsv?

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried the command from here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/QuickSync :

`ffmpeg -hwaccel qsv -c:v hevc_qsv -i input.mp4 -vf 'vpp_qsv=framerate=60,scale_qsv=w=1920:h=1080' -c:v h264_qsv output.mp4`

and replaced hevc_qsv with h264_qsv:

`ffmpeg -hwaccel qsv -c:v h264_qsv -i input.mp4 -vf 'vpp_qsv=framerate=60,scale_qsv=w=1920:h=1080' -c:v h264_qsv output.mp4`

This is the output I got:

```
WARNING: defaulting child_device_type to AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_DXVA2 for compatibility with old commandlines. This behaviour will be removed in the future. Please explicitly set device type via "-init_hw_device" option.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (h264_qsv) -> h264 (h264_qsv))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000016db059aac0] No such filter: 'scale_qsv=w=1920:h=1080'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
[aac @ 0000016db0c60740] Qavg: 65536.000
[aac @ 0000016db0c60740] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
```

I'm on a computer with an Intel 11th gen i5-1135G7, which I know supports the QSV encoders.

Comment: There is a chance that your FFmpeg version has no `scale_qsv` filter. Execute `ffmpeg -h filter=scale_qsv`, and verify the output is `QuickSync video scaling and format conversion...`. In case the message is `Unknown filter 'scale_qsv'`, update FFmpeg. What is the version of FFmpeg? What OS are you using Windows or Linux? Do you have dual GPU (Intel HD Graphics and external GPU like NVIDIA or only iGPU)?

Comment: I had already typed in the command, and it says "Filter scale_qsv QuickSync video scaling and format conversion" and then shows all the parameters. Just so u know, I've been using 3 different computers to test the various scaling filters, one of which has the Intel CPU (this one).

Comment: What is the version of FFmpeg? What OS are you using Windows or Linux? Do you have dual GPU (Intel HD Graphics and external GPU like NVIDIA or just Intel HD Graphics)?

Comment: I don't know if my answer is going to solve your issues, but it might help others...

Answer (score 0):

The following command works (for specific hardware and software configuration):

`ffmpeg -y -init_hw_device qsv=hw,child_device_type=dxva2 -hwaccel qsv -hwaccel_output_format qsv -c:v h264_qsv -i input.mp4 -vf "vpp_qsv=framerate=60,scale_qsv=w=640:h=480" -c:v h264_qsv output.mp4`

---

Build `input.mp4` for testing:
The `h264_qsv` decoder does not support `yuv444p` pixel format (at least not with my hardware).

For making sure that the pixel format is `yuv420p`, build `input.mp4` file (for testing):

`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=320x240:rate=10:duration=10 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p input.mp4`

---

Software configuration used for testing:

- Windows 10, with updated Intel HD Graphics driver.
- FFmpeg version 5.0.1-full_build-www.gyan.dev

Hardware configuration used for testing:

- Intel Core i7 Gen 6 (iGPU: Intel HD Graphics 530).
- **Main monitor is connected to Intel GPU** (when NVIDIA GPU is also present).

---

Note,
There is a warning message:

> [h264_qsv @ 0000025ac57dc040] A decode call did not consume any data: expect more data at input (-10)

But the output seems to be OK.