# FFMPEG hardware decoder is much slower than software decoder, why?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, hardware-acceleration

I'm new to ffmpeg. I want to convert videos to mjpeg (frame independent). At first I thought hardware acceleration should be faster. Then I tried both hardware decoders and software decoders:

```
"ffmpeg.exe" -y -hwaccel auto -ss 00:02:59 -to 00:04:17 -i "INPUT.mp4" -c:v mjpeg -q:v 1 -c:a pcm_s16le OUTPUT.mov
```

The result is:

```
frame= 1871 fps=127 q=1.0 Lsize=  447288kB time=00:01:17.99 bitrate=46980.0kbits/s speed= 5.3x
```

But,

```
"ffmpeg.exe" -y -ss 00:02:59 -to 00:04:17  -i "INPUT.mp4"  -c:v mjpeg  -q:v 1  -c:a pcm_s16le  OUTPUT.mov
```

the result is:

```
frame= 1871 fps=405 q=1.0 Lsize=  447288kB time=00:01:17.99 bitrate=46980.0kbits/s speed=16.9x
```

Hardware decoders are much slower than software decoders. How could this happen?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Could you describe your hardware? Also, what version of ffmpeg are you using?

Comment: `-hwaccel` will only really enable hardware acceleration for *input* and `-c:v mjpeg` will be a software encoder for both methods of encoding. If you have an nvidia card and want to use hardware acceleration then you should use an accelerated codec such as `-c:v h264_nvenc` (note the `nvenc`) see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro for more info. The reason for slowness might be that the hardware decoder needs to convert pixel formats used by hardware to the one used by the software mjpeg encoder as well as copying the buffer from the GPU decoder to CPU RAM..

Comment: Thank you. The CPU is i7-1255U. Windows 11 Pro. FFmpeg is 2023-06-15-git-41229ef705-full_build-www.gyan.dev. @music2myear

Comment: If your CPU has Intel graphics then you might be able to use `-c:v mjpeg_qsv` for Intel quicksync hardware encoding. Otherwise use the command `ffmpeg -encoders` to list the encoders available. `qsv` would denote Intel hardware acceleration `nvenc` would denote Nvidia acceleration and `amf` would (I believe) denote AMD hardware acceleration.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried `"ffmpeg.exe"  -y   -hwaccel auto  -ss 00:02:59 -to 00:04:17  -i "INPUT.mp4" -c:v mjpeg_qsv   -c:a pcm_s16le   OUTPUT.mov` The result is `frame= 1871 fps=221 q=-0.0 Lsize=  367342kB time=00:01:17.99 bitrate=38583.0kbits/s speed=9.22x` It is still much slower than software method. Am I missing something else? @Mokubai

Comment: @Ryan I no longer have any Intel hardware with which to try but from what I can find on the internet ffmpeg and Intel hardware needs a lot more options to push the decoder and encoder chain in the right direction regarding what kind of buffers to use and what pixel formats to pass. Check the answer at https://superuser.com/questions/1723544/ffmpeg-how-can-i-upscale-a-video-using-scale-qsv which looks like it has a far more in depth command line beyond simply specifying `-hwaccel auto` which may not be selecting the right decoder or formats.

Comment: I tried `"ffmpeg.exe"  -y   -hwaccel qsv   -ss 00:02:59 -to 00:04:17  -i "INPUT.mp4"   -c:v mjpeg_qsv   -global_quality 25  -look_ahead 1  -c:a pcm_s16le   OUTPUT.mov`  The result is `frame= 1871 fps=772 q=-0.0 Lsize=  161159kB time=00:01:17.99 bitrate=16927.0kbits/s speed=32.2x`  I don't know if I can push it further, but the  hardware method is finally faster than software method.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if `-hwaccel auto` might be selecting a DirectX decoder which might get a bad format compared to `qsv` and that would have been my next suggestion.

Comment: Thank you so much. I read the ffmpeg offical docs. Here is the [link](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#:~:text=Unlike%20most%20other%20values%2C%20this%20option%20does%20not%20enable%20accelerated%20decoding%20(that%20is%20used%20automatically%20whenever%20a%20qsv%20decoder%20is%20selected)%2C%20but%20accelerated%20transcoding%2C%20without%20copying%20the%20frames%20into%20the%20system%20memory.)  @Mokubai

Comment: Every software decoder _is_ a hardware decoder.  "Hardware decoder" is typically just a reference to one's having specialty hardware for decoding (or encoding, etc.).  If your specialty hardware is not all that special or, as others noted, its use requires expensive data conversion before it can start the video decoding, perhaps it'll be slower.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that part of the reason why it's slower in your setup is because you're asking the GPU to do the decoding but the CPU to do the encoding.

In such a scenario, the video data needs to be transferred between the memory and the GPU and then back to the CPU and the video data formats between them may need to be transcoded. Hence between the bus transfers between the GPU, memory and CPU and the transcoding of formats it becomes slow then all CPU based decoding and encoding.

You would really be able to see the performance increase if you're just decoding into raw video or if you're decoding and encoding through the GPU without any additional non GPU filters (which would cause the video to be copied back into the memory for the CPU to handle) to reduce the transfer and transcode overhead.