# Constructing encoding statements using ffmpeg QSV and Intel ARC card

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, encoding, intel-graphics

I purchased an Intel ARC A770 with the intent to test hardware encoding with AV1 and HEVC under Linux. Being newer to ffmpeg, I need help constructing ffmpeg statements to engage the Intel QSV encoders using the ARC card for HEVC and AV1. Thank you for your time and consideration. After a good bit of research, this is what I've figured out so far.

Operating system along with libraries and ffmpeg were all recently compiled from source within the last few weeks.

FFMpeg - Was compiled with `-libvpl` flag enabled to engage oneVPL API stack.

Software x265 encoding works fine. I successfully ran this-

```bash
ffmpeg -y -v verbose -i "Input.mkv" -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 -filter_complex "[0:0]scale=1920:-2:flags=lanczos,setsar=1:1,zscale=t=linear:npl=100,format=gbrpf32le,zscale=p=bt709,tonemap=tonemap=reinhard:desat=2,zscale=t=bt709:m=bt709:r=tv,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -c:v libx265 -crf:v 18 -preset:v slow Output.mkv
```

HEVC_QSV hardware encoding works but I'm honestly not sure what encoding path is being used here. Especially with having to use the hardware filter to copy from system memory to GPU. My preference is to use the latest OneVPL API path to engage the latest toolsets. I successfully ran this with hevc_qvc encoder-

```bash
ffmpeg -init_hw_device qsv=hw -filter_hw_device hw -v verbose -i Input.mkv -filter:v "scale=1920:-2,flags=lanczos,unsharp=5:5:.03:5:5:0.0" -c:v hevc_qsv -preset veryslow -extbrc 1 -look_ahead_depth 99 -b_strategy 1 -bf 7 -mbbrc 1 -rdo 1 -low_power 0 -adaptive_i 1 -adaptive_b 1 -async_depth 7 -b:v 25M -color_range tv -color_primaries:v bt709 -color_trc:v bt709 -colorspace:v bt709 Output.mkv
```

```bash
Video Card- ARC Sparkle A770
Linux Kernel- 6.6.10-1-default
LSCPU- Xeon- 2019 Xeon 12/24 cores including HT
Architecture: x86_64
CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit
Address sizes: 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
Byte Order: Little Endian
CPU(s): 24
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-23
Vendor ID: GenuineIntel
Model name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4214 CPU @ 2.20GHz
CPU family: 6
Model: 85
Thread(s) per core: 2
Core(s) per socket: 12
Socket(s): 1
Stepping: 7
```

```bash
VAINFO-
trying display: wayland
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is invalid or not set in the environment.
Trying display: x11
error: can't connect to X server!
Trying display: drm
libva info: VA-API version 1.20.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib64/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_20
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.20 (libva 2.20.1)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel iHD driver for Intel(R) Gen Graphics - 23.4.3 ()
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
VAProfileNone : VAEntrypointVideoProc
VAProfileNone : VAEntrypointStats
VAProfileMPEG2Simple : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileMPEG2Main : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileH264Main : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileH264Main : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
VAProfileH264High : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileH264High : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
VAProfileJPEGBaseline : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileJPEGBaseline : VAEntrypointEncPicture
VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
VAProfileHEVCMain : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileHEVCMain : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
VAProfileHEVCMain10 : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileHEVCMain10 : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
VAProfileVP9Profile0 : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileVP9Profile0 : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
VAProfileVP9Profile1 : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileVP9Profile1 : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
VAProfileVP9Profile2 : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileVP9Profile2 : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
VAProfileVP9Profile3 : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileVP9Profile3 : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
VAProfileHEVCMain12 : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileHEVCMain422_10 : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileHEVCMain422_10 : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
VAProfileHEVCMain422_12 : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileHEVCMain444 : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileHEVCMain444 : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
VAProfileHEVCMain444_10 : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileHEVCMain444_10 : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
VAProfileHEVCMain444_12 : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileHEVCSccMain : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileHEVCSccMain : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
VAProfileHEVCSccMain10 : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileHEVCSccMain10 : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
VAProfileHEVCSccMain444 : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileHEVCSccMain444 : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
VAProfileAV1Profile0 : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileAV1Profile0 : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
VAProfileHEVCSccMain444_10 : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileHEVCSccMain444_10 : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
```

```bash
FFMpeg version-
ffmpeg version N-113416-gcb6a488fba Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 13 (SUSE Linux)
configuration: --disable-debug --disable-doc --sws-max-filter-size=256 --host-os='SUSE Linux' --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libzimg --enable-libplacebo --enable-libass --enable-ladspa --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvmaf --enable-libopus --enable-libbluray --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-librav1e --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libvpl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-vulkan --enable-opencl --enable-openssl --disable-nvdec --disable-nvenc --disable-vdpau
libavutil 58. 36.101 / 58. 36.101
libavcodec 60. 38.100 / 60. 38.100
libavformat 60. 20.100 / 60. 20.100
libavdevice 60. 4.100 / 60. 4.100
libavfilter 9. 17.100 / 9. 17.100
libswscale 7. 6.100 / 7. 6.100
libswresample 4. 13.100 / 4. 13.100
libpostproc 57. 4.100 / 57. 4.100
```

```bash
FFMPEG -hwaccels
Hardware acceleration methods:
vaapi
qsv
drm
opencl
vulkan
```

```bash
fmpeg -hide_banner -encoders|grep av1
V....D librav1e librav1e AV1 (codec av1)
V..... libsvtav1 SVT-AV1(Scalable Video Technology for AV1) encoder (codec av1)
V..... av1_qsv AV1 (Intel Quick Sync Video acceleration) (codec av1)
V....D av1_vaapi AV1 (VAAPI) (codec av1)
```

```bash
ffmpeg -hide_banner -decoders|grep av1
V....D av1 Alliance for Open Media AV1
V....D av1_qsv AV1 video (Intel Quick Sync Video acceleration) (codec av1)
```

```bash
ffmpeg -hide_banner -encoders|grep hevc
V....D libx265 libx265 H.265 / HEVC (codec hevc)
V..... hevc_qsv HEVC (Intel Quick Sync Video acceleration) (codec hevc)
V....D hevc_vaapi H.265/HEVC (VAAPI) (codec hevc)
```

```bash
ffmpeg -hide_banner -codecs|grep hevc
DEV.L. hevc H.265 / HEVC (High Efficiency Video Coding) (decoders: hevc hevc_qsv hevc_v4l2m2m) (encoders: libx265 hevc_qsv hevc_v4l2m2m
hevc_vaapi)
```

```bash
ffmpeg -hide_banner -codecs|grep av1
DEV.L. av1 Alliance for Open Media AV1 (decoders: av1 av1_qsv) (encoders: librav1e libsvtav1 av1_qsv av1_vaapi)
```

Comment: Please focus your post in only one subject. Asking too many questions in one post is not recommended - it means that someone have to know to answer all your questions for getting an accepted answer. I recommend you to start with a simple question, and check if you are getting answered. In case you don't want hybrid (CPU / GPU) pipeline, replace `scale` with `scale_qsv` and use `vpp_qsv` for unsharping. Use `ffmpeg -h filter=vpp_qsv` for getting the filter documentation (`vpp_qsv` is working in Windows, but I never tried it in Linux).

Comment: @Rotem Thank you for the post etiquette.  I will edit my post.

Comment: `-c:v hevc_qsv` uses Intel Quick Sync (hardware accelerated) encoder. The `scale` and `unsharp` filters are executed on the CPU. You may also try `-c:v av1_qsv` to check if AV1 encoding is working. For hardware accelerated decoding, add `-hwaccel qsv` before the `-i`. The Intel Xeon Silver 4214 CPU, doesn't have an integrated GPU so the the encoding is performed in the ARC A770. What is the question?

Comment: Thanks on VPP filters. I read the man and see there are some options I will have to experiment with.

Comment: Forgive me if I didn't make myself clear. I'm aware hevc_qsv engages the QuickSync encoder.  I also understand my Xeon only has CPU (Software, Performance Instruction Sets) capabilities. Hence the new ARC card.  The ffmpeg Quicksync Wiki states there are 5 different APIs to engage the GPU hardware and it's capabilities. LibVPL, VAAPI with iHD driver, libmfx (Intel Media SDK), VAAPI with i965 driver.  Intel Media SDK is legacy and will/is being replace with OneVPL.

Comment: In the year 2024 with the latest linux kernel, ffmpeg version, Intel driver stack etc. installed, what commands do I need in ffmpeg to engage the complete lastest OneVPL API path for HEVC and AV1 using the hardware pipline for decoding, frame processing (VPP), and encoding?  This allows access to more advanced video frame analysis through software EncTools such as LookAhead parameter and others before being handed to the raw hardware encoder.

Comment: ffmpeg -hwaccel qsv -v verbose -i input.mkv -c:v av1_qsv -preset slow -b:v 15M output.mkv

Comment: Stream #0:0(eng): Video: av1, 1 reference frame (AV01 / 0x31305641), qsv(tv, progressive, left), 1920x1080 (0x0) [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 15000 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 1k tbn (default)encoder         : Lavc60.38.100 av1_qsv
[out#0/matroska @ 0x43727c0] Starting thread...
EHW Exception: vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 255) >= this->size() (which is 4)
[av1_qsv @ 0x4350540] Invalid FrameType:0.
[vost#0:0/av1_qsv @ 0x434e5c0] Error submitting video frame to the encoder
[vost#0:0/av1_qsv @ 0x434e5c0] Error encoding a frame: Invalid data found when processing input

Comment: I don't know why `av1_qsv` is not working. I don't have enough experience with Linux, and never tried to build FFmpeg from sources. I don't have experience with VAAPI (not exist in Windows). OneVPL and iHD driver is the newer framework, so we have to use it, and not the legacy (I think FFmpeg version 6 and above supports OneVPL). I don't know about "access to more advanced video frame analysis through software EncTools such as LookAhead parameter and others before being handed to the raw hardware encoder".

Comment: Thanks for your help Rotem.  So far nothing about ffmpeg and the technology stack required to run it has been straightforward, clear, and easy.

Comment: "Intel’s advanced software bitrate controller (dubbed “EncTools”) has been designed to boost GPU video quality for AVC, HEVC and AV1 using various compression efficiency technologies and content adaptive quality optimization tools while at the same time having minimal impact on the coding performance (speed). EncTools technology includes tools such as adaptive pyramid quantization, persistence adaptive quantization, look ahead, advanced scene change detection and more."

https://github.com/intel/media-delivery/blob/master/doc/reference-command-lines.rst

Comment: "EncTools are engaged automatically with enabling external BRC (extbrc 1) and setting look ahead depth >= 1.
Positive look ahead depth will automatically enable EncTools BRC and all adaptive encoding tools. For low
power look ahead to engage with EncTools BRC, look ahead depth should be > mini-GoP size. Several adaptive
encoding tools can be disabled by engaging SMT or FFmpeg-QSV flags, such as, for example, AdaptiveI off
(disable scene cut detection) and AdaptiveB off (disable adaptive mini-GoP)."

https://github.com/intel/media-delivery/blob/master/doc/quality.rst#enctools-and-extbrc

Comment: Picture of OneVPL API and technology stack

https://imgur.com/a/RTFcG61

Comment: After a lot of finagling this finally enabled a full QSV hardware transcode pipeline on Linux with an intel ARC card.

fmpeg -y -v verbose -hwaccel qsv -hwaccel_output_format qsv -c:v h264_qsv -i input.mkv -vf "scale_qsv=w=1920:h=1080" -c:v h265_qsv -preset veryslow -global_quality 18 output.mkv

Based on your input to a question here.  I used the format you provided and modified it until it worked. Thanks for the help!

https://superuser.com/questions/1723544/ffmpeg-how-can-i-upscale-a-video-using-scale-qsv

Answer (score 0):

This set of arguments enabled a full QSV hardware transcode pipeline on SUSE Linux with an intel ARC card from an h264 source to a h265 target.

```
fmpeg -y -v verbose -hwaccel qsv -hwaccel_output_format qsv -c:v h264_qsv -i input.mkv -vf "scale_qsv=w=1920:h=1080" -c:v h265_qsv -preset veryslow -global_quality 18 output.mkv
```